# For $n>2$, is it possible to find $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that pairs are linearly independent, but all triples are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given $n>2$, I want to know if it is possible to find a set $V_n$ of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that each pair of vectors in $V_n$ are linearly independent, but each triple are linearly dependent. I have completed most of what I think will be able to prove this statement, but I am struggling with one detail.

**What I have argued is as follows:**

For $n=3$, this is possible, for example

$$V_3 = \Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\}$$

works.

My idea is to proceed by induction. We assume this is true for a set $V_k = \{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, ..., \mathbf{v}_k \}$ (for $k > 2$), and then construct a set $V_{k+1}$ that works, by first taking all $\mathbf{v}_i \in V_k$ and constructing a $k+1$ dimensional vector $\mathbf{w}_i$ defined by

$$(\mathbf{w}_i)_j=\Bigg\{\begin{array}{ll}
      (\mathbf{v}_i)_j & j\in\{1,...,k\} \\
      0 & j=k+1
\end{array} $$

and then constructing another vector $\mathbf{w}_{k+1}$ somehow. Clearly all of the $\mathbf{w}_i$ for $i\in\{1,...,k\}$ are non-zero and linearly independent in pairs, and linearly dependent in triples by the inductive hypothesis and noting that for any $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\alpha\mathbf{w}_i+\beta\mathbf{w}_j = \mathbf{0} \iff\alpha\mathbf{v}_i+\beta\mathbf{v}_j = \mathbf{0}$$

and similarly for the sum of any $3$ of the first $k$ vectors in $V_{k+1}$.

But now, I am not sure how to construct a suitable vector $\mathbf{w}_{k+1}$ that would be linearly independent with any of the other vectors in $V_{k+1}$, but linearly dependent with two of these other vectors.

Any help as to how I can complete this argument is much appreciated. Alternatively, any other way to prove (or disprove) this statement would be interesting to see.

Comment: Sure.  Just do it for the plane (easy) and then embed the plane in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it work just to take $e_1, e_1 + e_2, e_1 + 2 e_2, \ldots, e_1 + (n-1) e_2$ as the vectors?

Comment: @lulu , Daniel Schepler these methods are much easier, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

$$ V_n = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\.\\.\\.\\.\\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0
\end{pmatrix}, \cdots, 
\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0 \end{pmatrix}
 \right\} $$

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you can just take them all to be in the same plane. Let's say rotation of $(1,0,\ldots ,0)$ around some axis. You can get as much vectors as you want in this process (not only n).